# How to dismiss UIPopoverControllers that I don't have reference to?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a number of BarButtons in my toolbar, and I want to show a different UIPopoverController for each of them. When I click on one of them, other PopoverControllers should be dismissed (i.e. only one popovercontroller is shown on the screen). I don't want to keep references to them -- because that's too annoying. Is there another way to dismiss them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "dismiss all popovers" function that I know of.

But to solve this, you don't have to keep references to all of your different popovers; only keep a reference to the currently showing popover. Then when a new popover is launched, you can dismiss that currently showing popover (if it is not nil). Then assign "currently showing popover" to the new popover you display.

Comment: I guess this is the best way at the moment. I wonder why apple does not provide a way similar to [controller dismissModelViewController:]

Comment: How to dismiss the popover if it is comes from dictionary (textfield)

Answer (score 1):

Using the automated testing framework KIF brought me to the idea to look at their dismissPopovers function.

I modified this function a little bit, so you could really use a global dismiss all popovers function. 
Here is the code:

```
    //dismiss popovers
    NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
    for(UIView *currentPopover in [[windows objectAtIndex:0] subviewsWithClassNamePrefix:@"UIDimmingView"]) {
       [currentPopover removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

And the UIViewExtension:

```
- (NSArray *)subviewsWithClassNamePrefix:(NSString *)prefix;
{
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Breadth-first population of matching subviews
    // First traverse the next level of subviews, adding matches.
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) hasPrefix:prefix]) {
            [result addObject:view];
        }
    }

    // Now traverse the subviews of the subviews, adding matches.
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        NSArray *matchingSubviews = [view subviewsWithClassNamePrefix:prefix];
        [result addObjectsFromArray:matchingSubviews];
    }

    return result;
```

}

Thanks to [KIF](https://github.com/square/KIF) for the hints

Answer (score 0):

As per the developers document from **[here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)** Taps outside of the popover’s contents automatically dismiss the popover. but you can use this method `dismissPopoverAnimated` to dismiss the popover programmatically in response to taps inside the popover window.Like for example you can dissmiss it in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate of `UIImagePickerController`

Hope you get it...Good Luck!